# Postgres settings for Django on Google App Engine Flexi

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to setup django with postgres on app engine flexible environment.

I followed the instructions from here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres

My django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': '<db-name>',
            'USER': '<user-name>',
            'PASSWORD': '<password>',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/<instance-connection-name>,
            'PORT': '5432'
        },
}
```

app.yaml:

```
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <instance-connection-name>
```

Error I am getting is:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server
>   running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/cloudsql/`<instance-connection-name>`/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Please help with the correct settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem resolved itself. I didn't change anything in my code. Here are the steps to use postgresql with django in app engine flexible environment:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/870

**EDIT:**

You have to enable the cloud sql api to get it running properly.

checkout this comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/870#issuecomment-298152847

Comment: As an explanation on why it was not working: looks like you tried to do this shortly after the launch and let's say we (Google Cloud teams) did not time all of updates perfectly, so AppEngine was a bit behind the announcement.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, it ends up that I had skipped enabling the [sqladmin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin).

To see if this is the problem you can check the logs for the instance. Near the top (before gunicorn starts) there will be an error along the lines of:

```
googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has not been used in project ######## before or it is disabled.
```

That check is made only when the instance first starts, so once you've enabled the API, you need to re-deploy or otherwise restart your instances. Many of the people reporting this issue elsewhere talk about it magically fixing itself, and I'm guessing the instances got restarted.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot after tearing my hair out!

Answer (score -1):

If you turn on api and it does not help try to change database engine in Django

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
```

to

```
 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```