# Is it possible to connect to a google cloud sql postgres instance from app engine flexible using golang?

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

I was able to find This document which explains how to do it from python : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres

I could not find anything equivalent for golang. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible.

*Disclaimer*: I have not tried to actually do that, so there may be typos / small errors in what follows. Also I'd like to assure you that CloudSQL documentation team is aware and working on adding examples for other languages including Go.

Under the guts AppEngine Flex runs [CloudSQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) for you and your code connects to CloudSQL via usual driver using unix socket.

So while there is no example for Go, it should be fairly easy. Assuming you use standard Go's sql library and reading https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq looks like you need something like this in your code:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=username password=password host=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME dbname=databasename")
```

Or, if you use different format or library, just make sure to specify `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` for host parameter.

Also, make sure to follow all non-Python specific steps of https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres.

PS: here's example for Django: [Postgres settings for Django on Google App Engine Flexi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950418/postgres-settings-for-django-on-google-app-engine-flexi?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer above is correct, but I just wanted to note here that Google has now added official documentation that explains the same thing in details here

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-sql-postgres

Comment: I don't see any golang documentation there. Are you sure your link is correct?

Comment: You are right. That url redirects now to a completely useless MySQL related page. Looks like google re-organized their documentation yet again and all the golang stuff is gone. So, the parent answer is now useless. Sigh.

Comment: The samples in github are probably a better place to look : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine_flexible/cloudsql_postgres